# Problem downloading Java JDK with WGET on Ubuntu

Tags: java, wget

I'm attempting to install the Java JDK through the command line using `WGET` on [ubuntu](/questions/tagged/ubuntu) (no desktop).

Here is the picture I took. The file that was downloaded was not the tar ball of the JDK:

How can I download it via WGET?

[image]

Comment: Unless something has changed the links on Oracles site are generated -per session-. So the link you generated from one machine will not download from a different machine using wget, since the oracle website has no clue who the new session is and why it has links from a different session. I manged to work around this in the past by downloading from the machine that generated the link and then uploaded to the linux/unix box via SCP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you see the resulting file the output it downloads a file of type: text/html.
If you open the resulting file, you will find that it has in it's content the following:

"Network you must agree to the OTN license terms."

Which is what you have to do during webpage browsing.

But a quick google search I found this:

```
wget --no-cookies --header "Cookie: gpw_e24=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.oracle.com%2Ftechnetwork%2Fjava%2Fjavase%2Fdownloads%2Fjdk-7u17-download-1501626.html;" http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u17-b02/jdk-7u17-linux-x64.rpm --no-check-certificate -O jdk-7u17-linux-x64.rpm
```

[Source](http://news.thedigitalmachine.com/2013/04/03/one-liner-to-download-oracle-jdk-7u17-with-wget/)

Comment: change the file name for the correct one ... it's a example of a working command.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ wget --no-cookies --no-check-certificate \
     --header "Cookie: gpw_e24=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.oracle.com" \
     "http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u21-b11/jdk-7u21-linux-x64.rpm
```

Substitute your URL into the example above.

#### References

- [How to automate download and instalation of Java JDK on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10268583/how-to-automate-download-and-instalation-of-java-jdk-on-linux)